# How to PUT / UPDATE nested data with GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I'm attempting my first GraphQL backend using AWS AppSync. I'm simply trying to figure out how to use one-to-many associations. I expect to receive the many related objects as a list of children, and to be able to write some of these children when creating a new user.

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    records: [Records!]!
}
type Records {
    id: ID!
    userId: ID!
    title: String!
    ... etc ...
}
```

Using the AppSync interface, I click on `Create Resources` once to make a Records table and again to make a Users table, both in DynamoDB. This also automatically adds mutations, subscriptions, input types, and more types, to my schema, and creates resolvers for me.

What is the syntax for a mutation to create Record objects associated with my User objects? How can I PUT the Record data when I create the User?

If needed I can include more of the schema that AppSync is autogenerating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using two DynamoDB tables (Users and Records), you will need to make two DynamoDB calls during the CreateUser mutation. One way to make two DynamoDB calls in a single mutation is to utilize DynamoDB's **BatchPutItem** operation.

To utilize BatchPutItem, you will need to modify the **resolver** which is attached to your CreateUser mutation. The resolver is responsible for taking your graphQL request, converting it into a DynamoDB operation, and then converting the results of the DynamoDB operation into a graphQL response. The resolvers have two components: a request mapping template, and a response mapping template.

The **request mapping template** will be responsible for taking mutation arguments and converting them into a DynamoDB BatchPutItem request.

The resolver's **response mapping template** will be responsible for converting the result of the DynamoDB BatchPutItem operation into your mutation's return type/structure.

Here is a tutorial on how to utilize multi-table BatchPutItem in a resolver: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html

Here is a programming guide for using the Template language required for the resolvers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-programming-guide.html