# Nested mutation GraphQL

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Appsync and Amplify.
A snippet of my GraphQL schema look like this:

```
type Recipe
@model
@auth(rules: [{allow: owner}])
{
 id: ID!
 title: String!
 key: String!
 courses: [Course!]!
}

type Course
@model
@auth(rules: [{allow: owner}])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

On amplify push it creates the DynamoDB tables `Recipe` and `Course`

After reading many tutorials I still don't get it how to add a recipe in GraphiQL.

How can i insert a new Recipe that has a reference to a course and avoid duplicates in the Courses table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create multiples `Recipe` referencing the same `Course` without duplicates in the `Course` table, you need to design a many-to-many relationship.

So far the relationship you have designed is not enough for AppSync to understand, you are missing `@connection` attributes. You can read [this answer on github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/91#issuecomment-419226819) to have an explanation of how to design this many-to-many relation in AppSync

After designing the relation, you will use a mutation to insert data, and it's likely that AppSync will generate the mutation code for you (if not, use `amplify codegen` in the console). You will then be able to create data.

Since you use DynamoDB with multiple tables (default mode for amplify / AppSync), you will have to either :

- Call multiple mutations in a row
- Use a custom resolver, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624580/how-to-put-update-nested-data-with-graphql)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created a many-to-many relationship. But still a bit confused how the mutation should like. I can not create a Recipe to the database with Courses attached in one mutation call right? So first I have to create a Recipe, remember it's ID and then attache a Course to it in an extra mutation call?

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me pointing in the right direction here. First time serverless and noSQL :P It's some sort of a mindshift

Comment: But for query the data you can show the associated Courses in one call without changing the resolver?

Comment: Yes one query to Recipe will give you nested Course if you ask for it